# Scrum as a software development methology

Tags: scrum

Which organisations are best suited for use of Scrum methodology and why?

Comment: Partial Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/343254/is-scrum-fit-for-small-organisation

Comment: Organisations? Do you mean firms/companies, or how the development team should be organized, or what? I think organisations use Scrum, not the other way round :-)

Comment: Huge question - I don't think it can be answered here. Could you be more specific? Are you investigating Scrum specifically or Agile in general? If Scrum in the context of Agile then what other models and practices are you considering? Organisations is a broad term too - are you asking whether Scrum is better suited to big companies vs little, or public sector vs private?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [project management is now off-topic on Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343829/is-stack-overflow-an-appropriate-website-to-ask-about-project-management-issues/343841#343841). Ask these questions on [SoftwareEngineering.SE](//softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) and [ProjectManagement.SE](//pm.stackexchange.com/) instead. (Unfortunately, this question is too old to be  migrated.)

Answer (score 2):

Scrum is not a development methodology, it is a project management methodology. Scrum is about managing workload and resources, and removing impediments to progress, and surfacing results at regular intervals to the whole team (including stakeholders).

Think to yourself:

- could your dev/project teams benefit from a daily or bi-daily catchup meeting?
- when you have design or project meetings, do the wrong people hog all the attention?
- do you need to draw a distinction between various stake holders in a project?
- could your team benefit from an iterative process, where "releases" are done frequently (i.e. every 3 or 4 weeks), and bugs and features are carefully prioritised against each other by the product manager?

Answer (score 1):

The smallest team we have that uses something scrum-alike consists of 3 devellopers (2 full, 1 part-time), the stakeholder and the scrum-master ('secretary'). It works very well and we are planning to switch other small project teams to this method soon. 
There are some 'points' you have to keep in mind:

- We have the project status in an excel table under revision control, that is updated at least after the very short daily meeting.
- The review and planning meeting is scheduled biweekly on a given day and will not be moved until all participants agree.
- In all metings we break down the tasks from backloglist to smaller ones of max. 2 days of work, depending on the task type (concept, prototype, product etc). This proved to be the most valuable means to get reliable estimations!
- If the stakeholder needs an status update or needs to adjust priorisation he can have a look at the excel table and change it, so even if he's not participating the planning meeting he has enough impact on project devellopment
- The most important influence on management style is that you have evidence on what a given change would cost and what you can achieve until a given date (thing of a release date or a fair trade).

Comment: "Smallest"?  Odd point.  2 people don't need Scrum -- they're going to talk anyway.  1 person doesn't need Scrum.  Maybe you should omit the "smallest" part and focus on what you're doing that works.